# How wait for ec2 instance creation via cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

For example I run the following command:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --instance-type i3.xlarge --image-id ami-00000000 --user-data file://myfile.sh
```

This leads to instance creation start. Is there a way to execute this command and wait until EC2 is created and all status check are performed?

Answer (score 13):

You can use:

```
aws ec2 wait instance-status-ok
```

See:

- [instance-status-ok — AWS Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/wait/instance-status-ok.html)
- [instance-running — AWS Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/wait/instance-running.html)

Answer (score 6):

Grab the `INSTANCE_ID` when creating the instance:

```
INSTANCE_ID=$(aws ec2 run-instances --instance-type i3.xlarge --image-id ami-00000000 --user-data file://myfile.sh  --output text --query 'Instances[*].InstanceId')
```

And wait for the instance to reach a running state:

```
while STATE=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $INSTANCE_ID --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].State.Name'); test "$STATE" != "running"; do
    sleep 1;
done;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in the `run-instances` command directly, but you can obtain the instance ID of the new instance using `--query 'Instances[*].InstanceId' --output text`, and then run the [`wait instance-running`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/wait/instance-running.html) or [`wait instance-status-ok`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/wait/instance-status-ok.html) command on the instance ID, like so:

```bash
instance_id="$(aws ec2 run-instances \
    --query 'Instances[*].InstanceId' --output text \
    --region us-east-1 \
    [your arguments]
)" &&
aws ec2 wait instance-running --instance-ids "$instance_id" --region us-east-1
```

If you want to wait for status checks rather just the "running" state, replace `wait instance-running` with `wait instance-status-ok`.